# How can I switch out the content area on a page on a button click in the same area with Aurelia?

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

What do I need to add so that when a user clicks on the `Current Period` button, the entire area (which is shaded in the second image for clarity) is replaced with the content of the page controlled by `periods.js` and `periods.html`? I have already tried `click.delegate` (shown in second block of code below) and made other futile attempts. Any hints would be greatly appreciated. Feel free to tell me if more code needs shown. Thank you!

Here is the first image:
[How the page looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RduN6.jpg)

Here is the second image:
[Area shaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwZ1n.jpg)

```js
System.register([], function (_export) {
  'use strict';

  var History;

  var _createClass = (function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ('value' in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; })();

  function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError('Cannot call a class as a function'); } }

  return {
    setters: [],
    execute: function () {
      History = (function () {
        function History() {
          _classCallCheck(this, History);

          this.heading = 'History';
        };

        return History;
      })();

      _export('History', History);
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<template>
  <section class="au-animate">
    <h2>${heading}</h2>
    <br>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
      <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="margin:1px" click.delegate="dist/periods.js">Current Period</button></li>
    <br>
    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="margin:1px">Past Period Mango</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="margin:1px">Past Period Pommelo</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="margin:1px">Past Period Kiwi</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="margin:1px">Past Period Clementine</button></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing that `click.delegate="..."` should be a function of your viewmodel.

Then it should be a matter of adding `show.bind="..."` to the right elements and toggling that property inside the function you've delegated the click to.